# how to make post requests using with list as parameters in python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-ads-api

I want make a post call for facebook audience sharing API

here is the method

---

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/{audienceid}/adaccounts
```

but addcounts and audienceid are two lists

addaccounts and audienceid look something like this

---

```
addaccounts = [1337845464515, 13464645456566]

audienceid = ['6018213515', '601816526']
```

how to concatenate and make post requests

Comment: Make multiple requests?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco how to make multiple requests according to above api?

Comment: So for the given 4 values (2 `addaccounts` and 2 `audienceid`) what do you want your program to do? You cannot put a list into the `audienceid` path element, for example.

Comment: Do you mean that each `audienceid` value is a graph node id and each `addaccounts` value is a edge name (as per the [graph API quickstart](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.0#structure))?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i want to share the audiences ids for all the account Id present id addaccounts

Comment: @shashisp: You mean you want to produce 4 different URLs? `https://graph.facebook.com/6018213515/1337845464515`, `https://graph.facebook.com/601816526/1337845464515`, `https://graph.facebook.com/6018213515/13464645456566`, `https://graph.facebook.com/601816526/13464645456566`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters here is the usage https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting#sharing  i have accountids and audience ids in the form of list

Comment: @shashisp: right, that was important information. You may want to [edit] your question to add that. Did you want to call both `https://graph.facebook.com/6018213515/adaccounts` *and* `https://graph.facebook.com/601816526/adaccounts`, passing in the `addaccounts` list to both?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  sendign audience id list to for all accounts as http://graph.facebook.com/audienceid/13378464515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if all POST methods in the [Custom Audience Targeting API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting) take query parameters that are encoded to JSON.

The sample given in the [Sharing Audiences call](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting#sharing) uses *integers* for the `adaccounts` values, so make sure yours are indeed integers before converting to JSON:

```
import json
import requests

adaccounts = [1337845464515, 13464645456566]
audienceid = ['6018213515', '601816526']

params = {adaccounts: json.dumps(adaccounts)}

for id_ in audienceid:
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{}/adaccounts'.format(id_)
    response = requests.post(url, data=params)
```

`requests` will then encode the `params` dictionary to a POST `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body.

This is ignoring the fact that you need to have the correct OAuth token.

Comment: i have tried requesting with `respone = requests.post(url, access_token, params=params) i got  <Response [400]> bad request

Comment: Mea Culpa; the request is a `POST` not a `GET` method. I Adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: yes! it got resolved, auth token need to be encoded along with the data, Thanks!